# InternetExplorer.Application .contentDocument : <Permission refused>

Tags: vba, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I'm in France...
I develop in VBA under Excel, I work with the object "InternetExplorer.Application" to browse a website and save the contents.
On the main page there is no problem, but when I load a page that normally opens in a popup, I can not retrieve the contents of the iframe:

```
<div id="fichecheval" data-zepro="hippodrome=DEAUVILLE&amp;dr=20170826&amp;nr=1&amp;nc=3&amp;nch=1">
<iframe src="//pro.zeturf.com/externe/zefiche_cheval_.php?hippodrome=DEAUVILLE&amp;dr=20170826&amp;nr=1&amp;nc=3&amp;nch=1&amp;ts=1503747108&amp;key=aecd0f4c33ce9588e38d7f8c6986ec778beeb88fffb940f07cfda0ec4a7768ab" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="min-height: 5000px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

my code :

```
Dim IFrame As HTMLDocument
Dim Content As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim FormulaireConnexion As Object
Dim login As Object
Dim Password As Object
Dim jour As Object
Dim mois As Object
Dim annee As Object
Dim MyTag As Object
'Références et zones de chargement
Dim MyAdr As String
'Gestion fichiers
Dim intFic As Integer
Dim MyFile As String

'******************************************
'Instantiation InternetExplorer.Application
'******************************************
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'IE.Silent = True
IE.Visible = True
'*******************************
'Connexion avec authentification
'*******************************
IE.navigate "https://www.zeturf.fr"
Do
DoEvents
Loop While IE.readyState <> 4 And IE.Busy = True
Sleep 1000
Set login = IE.document.getElementById("connection_login")
login.Value = "toto"
Set Password = IE.document.getElementById("connection_password")
Password.Value = "toto66"
Set jour = IE.document.getElementById("connection_jour")
jour.Value = "01"
Set mois = IE.document.getElementById("connection_mois")
mois.Value = "01"
Set annee = IE.document.getElementById("connection_annee")
annee.Value = "1966"
Set FormulaireConnexion = IE.document.getElementById("connection_submit")
FormulaireConnexion.Click
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False
Sleep 1000
'*****************
IE.navigate "https://www.zeturf.fr/fr/course/2017-08-26/R1C3-deauville-prix-de-la-reconversion-des-chevaux-de-courses-grand-handicap-de-la-manche/turf"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False
Sleep 1000
'*****************
MyAdr = "https://www.zeturf.fr/fr/course/2017-08-26/R1C3-deauville-prix-de-la-reconversion-des-chevaux-de-courses-grand-handicap-de-la-manche/turf/partants/2412257"
'_blank Load the link into a new unnamed window.
'_parent Load the link into the immediate parent of the document the link is in.
'_self Load the link into the same window the link was clicked in.
'_top Load the link into the full body of the current window.
IE.navigate MyAdr, , "_self"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False
Sleep 1000
'*****************
MyFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Courses\test.html"
intFic = FreeFile
Open MyFile For Output As intFic
Print #intFic, IE.document.body.innerHTML
'*****************
Set IFrame = IE.document.frames().document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0)
Set Content = IFrame.getElementsByTagName("html")
Set IFrame = Nothing
'*****************
Close intFic
```

On the "Set Content" I have the error "Permission denied" and when I look at the IFrame object in the spy window I have this:
IFrame: contentDocument: 
I tell myself that my navigation does not simulate the reality (no popup), but opening in the same tab or a second tab ...
Do you have any idea about the problem? Thank you for your help